# What is the difference of "take" operator's sequence in a chain

Tags: ios, rx-swift, reactivex

For example,

```
let observable1 = Observable<Void>.of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
.take(1)
.flatMap{_ in 
 doSomething()
}

let observable2 = Observable<Void>.of([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
.flatMap{_ in 
 doSomething()
}
.take(1)
```

my question is, what is the difference of this two Observable?
They looks same.

Answer (score 2):

If *upstream* (observable1/observable2) emits *N* items, `.flatMap()` operator emits *M* items , where *M* can be greater (usually), lesser or equal to *N*.

In your 1st example you are taking 1 item from the *N* items of the *upstream*. In the 2nd example you are taking 1 item from the the *M* items emitted by `.flatMap()` operator.

Comment: True, the first example can emit more than one item. The second example can't.